# Relative path of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I need simple help which I am not able to resolve regarding the relative path of a file. I am making this project in node and express. My file structure is:

src(folder):

```
     database.json
     routes(folder):

        api(folder):
             addbook.ts
```

Now I want to access my database file in addbook.ts using readFilesync, for that I need the relative path of the file.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your file structure. Is this how your project is set up? `src/database.json`   `src/routes/api/addbook.ts`

Comment: yes ,database.json is in my src folder and routes is inside src folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dirname` variable.

```
const databaseContents = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../database.json')
)
```